# Prove that $id_{\vec{X}} + f’ + (f’)^{2}+\cdots+(f’)^{n}=0$, where $f:X\to X$ is the bijective affine transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

If $X$ is an affine $n$ dimensional space over a field of characteristic bigger than $n+2$ and $(A_{0},A_{1},\ldots,A_{n})$ an affine frame of $X$, prove that $id_{\vec{X}} + f’ + (f‘)^{2}+\cdots+(f’)^{n}=0$,  where $f:X\to X$ is the bijective affine transformation defined as $f(A_{0})=A_{1}$, $f(A_{1})=A_{2}$, \ldots , $f(A_{n})=A_{0}$. I know how to find the passing matrix of this function from one frame to another, but I am stuck at that equality. Any help?

Comment: What is $f`$ here? And what is an affine reper? An affinely independent tuple of points such that each point is an affine combination of them?

Comment: It is the frame